# Combine multiple rows and count into new columns in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

create list of all writer and the count of  books they have written .
*Create one new column as writers name adding the first and last name from the writers table
*Get the count of books they have written in a new coulmns as number of books written
*Finally List to be ordered by Writers name , title and launch date

Im have created a simple question here as im trying to build something on similar ground:

Books:

[image: Books]

Writers:

[image: Writers]

Expected Result:

[image: result]

Comment: A MySQL 8.x window function can do that. Are you using MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM books b
INNER JOIN (
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS author,COUNT(*) As booksWritten
FROM books
GROUP BY CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) c
ON CONCAT(b.first_name,' ', b.last_name=c.author
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use a window function. For example:

```
select
  b.book_id,
  b.title,
  b.launch_date,
  concat(w.first_name, ' ', w.last_name) as writers_name,
  count(*) over(partition by w.first_name, w.last_name) as book_count
from book_table b
join write_table w on w.book_id = b.book_id
order by b.launch_date
```